# How do I POST/GET from rails to API with Nestful?

Tags: rest

this is a pretty basic question but I'm not entirely clear how to do this.

I am trying to use a third-party service that has web-based service.  The service is called Postful.  But I'm not clear what exactly to do?

I've looked at ActiveResource (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) and rest-client, but I'm still not clear exactly what steps, code, and files to create.

I'm trying to use Nestful but I'm not entirely clear how to make this work.  http://github.com/maccman/nestful

http://www.postful.com/service/mail is one of the services (details found http://www.postful.com/developer/guide#rest ), but to upload an image I have to post the following (but I'm not sure how I actually do this?).  Thanks!

```
> http://www.postful.com/service/upload
> 
> Be sure to include the Content-Type
> and Content-Length headers and the
> image itself as the body of the
> request.
> 
> POST /upload HTTP/1.0 Content-Type:
> application/octet-stream
> Content-Length: 301456
> 
> ... file content here ...
> 
> If the upload is successful, you will
> receive a response like the following:
> 
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <upload>  
> <id>290797321.waltershandy.2</id>
> </upload>
```

Comment: Have you been able to determine whether they have a RESTful interface for uploading files?

Comment: I don't think so -- the only interface is the one described above.... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nestful is really easy, you should be able to just do this:

```
Nestful.post 'http://www.postful.com/service/upload', :format => :multipart, :user => 'foo', :password => 'bar', :params => {:file => File.open('YOUR_FILE')}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at their API and it doesn't seem like attachment uploading is RESTful - it looks like only mail order creation is. So, ActiveResource won't do the trick here.

Depending on your dev/production environment, you might want to look into using something more generic like `curl`.

From the manual: curl is a tool to transfer data from or to a server... The command is designed to work without user interaction.

You'll want something like this:

```
# Encode your username:password as base64
USERNAME="youremail@example.com"
PASSWORD="yourpostfulpassword"
BASE64_ENCODED_AUTH = `echo $USERNAME:PASSWORD | base64`

curl -F "@path/to/file/to/upload;type=application/octet-stream" http://$BASE64_ENCODED_AUTH@www.postful.com/service/upload
```

I haven't tested this as I don't have a username/password - but it should get you on the right track.

You can put this in a script in `/lib` and call it from your controller using your preferred method.

**Edit:**

So I tried this with a dummy username and password, and using the `--verbose` flag to `curl`, and the headers looked right. I also got a `401 UNAUTHORISED` response so it looks like it's working right.

Comment: Have you used Nestful, it looks like a way to interace with HTTP and REST API....

Comment: I haven't used Nestful - did you give `curl` a try? After a brief look at Nestful it seems like you're gonna be calling `Nestful.post url, options = {}` (unless postful *does* have RESTful attachment uploading) which is going to be pretty much equivalent to using `curl`, except you're writing it in Ruby rather than bash.